# How to calculate max affordability

Tags: education, reduction-formula

If a house requires 20% down-payment and someone has 80K, what would be the house price?

Is there a formula to calculate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$20$% is $\frac{1}{5}$. Therefore the maximum price would be $5$ times the available deposit.

For your problem this is 400K.

Comment: thank you, havent used math in a while